# Deformation retract needs to be smooth?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

So I am not quite sure that why none of these three is a deformation retract - is that because of the corners? But I don't remember deformation retract rely on smooth criteria, instead, on continuous ones.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A space is a deformation retract of another only if it's a subspace of the latter.